# Sysdate different than database date in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sysdate

I am using SQL Developer as a client for an Oracle 11G RAC. The database server is set to Pacific Daylight Timezone (PDT) and when I query `sysdate` in sqlplus, it always shows the PDT time. But in SQL Developer it displays time as GMT -4.

The system date on the system where SQL Developer is running is also set to PDT, even if I changed from Central timezone. I tried to add this parameter to the SQL Developer configuration files:

`AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT-7`

But I continue to see the following results:

From SQL Developer:

```
select to_char(current_date,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'), to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'), sessiontimezone from dual;
```

> CURRENT_DATE SYSDATE SESSIONTIMEZONE
>
> 09-AUG-13 12:57:11 10-AUG-13 03:57:11  -07:00

From sqlplus:

```
SQL> select to_char(current_date,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'), to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'), sessiontimezone from dual;
```

> TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'DD-MO TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYH
>
> ---
>
> SESSIONTIMEZONE
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 09-AUG-13 12:55:11          09-AUG-13 12:55:11 -07:00
> ```

Anyone knows how to have the same output as generated by sqlplus?

I have to schedule jobs in a production environment and I guess it is better to use `sysdate` instead of the `current_date`.

Comment: I edited your question. You should clarify the following part: "...even if I changed from Central timezone." Also, you may want to properly format the output of the second SQL statement.

Comment: @Sabuncu, thanks for your edit. What I wanted to say is that I changed the timezome of the system where I am running SQL Developer (that is my laptop) when I moved to the PDT timezone and before it was set to CEST (Central European Summer Time) but I don't know if it could be related to the issue.